# numpy - get random integers as floats

Tags: python, numpy, casting

So in a fixedpoint iteration, I've changed the way the matrix is initialised from

```
def init(M,N):
    return 2.5*np.ones([M,N])
```

to

```
def init(M,N):
    return nprnd.randint(1,6,[M,N])
```

where

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprnd
```

this immediately caused

> A -= step_size * G
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'

big deal, I'll just

```
nprnd.randint(1,6,[M,N], dtype='float')
```

*except*

> TypeError: Unsupported dtype "float64" for randint

How do I circumvent this? I kind of don't want to generate a Matrix and then copy it just to cast it to float. Is there a more intelligent way?

Comment: If you want random float values between those ranges you can also use [np.random.random_sample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html) to create the matrix `5 * np.random.random_sample((M,N)) + 1`.

Comment: @umutto Thank you, but I want ints, I just *need* them as floats.

Comment: @User1291 Could you show a bit more code then? In particular, what is `G`, what is `A`, what is `step_size`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do an explicit cast using `astype`:

```
nprnd.randint(1,6,[M,N]).astype("float")
```

Comment: Yup, but that copies the array. Is there no way to avoid that?